# lisp sort list via function

Tags: list, function, sorting, lisp

I am trying to use lisp's sort to sort a list via a function but dont have a clue how to do this.
I have a start-point in 2D Space with x and y coordinates. Then i have a List of N-other points and i have a function that calculates the distance between 2 points.
What I want now is a list, that contains all the N-Points and is sorted by distance ascending from the start-point to all other points.

I think I can use the sort-function and pass a function as argument (the calculate-distance function) But i dont know how to do it and researches on the web did not help.

Any ideas?

Regards

Comment: Which lisp do you use?

Answer (score 8):

Use `:key` with [`sort`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_sort_.htm):

```
(sort list #'< :key (lambda (p) (dist p start-point)))
```

This will sort the `list` of points in the increasing order (use `>` for decreasing) based on the distance to `start-point`.

Answer (score 2):

If you use common lisp, I recommend you the [Common Lisp Hyper Spec](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/FrontMatter/index.html) project. In your case the documentation to the [`sort`](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/fun_sortcm_stable-sort.html) function will be useful. Here you can see, that it has a second parameter: *predicate*. The *predicate* takes two arguments and returns whether the second is greather then the first one.

Let's say you have a function `dist`, measuring a distance between two points. To compare two points by the distance to your `start-point`, you need the following lambda:

```
#'(lambda (p1 p2) (> (dist p1 start-point) (dist p2 start-point)))
```

So you have to place it in the place of predicate (the second position) in `sort` argument list.