# Create a new Sort in LISP

Tags: sorting, common-lisp

I want to define a new sorting method in LISP that sticks to this formula.

2 > 3 > 4 > 5 > 6 > 7 > 8 > 9 > 10 > J > Q > K > A

As seen in Poker.

So for example I called it on this:

```
(mysortmethod '((3 H)(2 H)(J D)(8 C)(5 C)))
```

I would get this:

```
((2 H)(3 H)(5 C)(8 C)(J D))
```

as the sorted list where the 2nd element in each bracket is ignored.

I have absolutely no idea how to do this. Could someone point me in the right direction or perhaps explain to me a method?

Comment: The LISP `sort` function allows you to specify a sorting function and key. See the online documentation and Google for examples. Here's [one example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385099/lisp-sort-list-via-function), on stackoverflow.com. You just need to create a function that can compare two elements per your desired order. You can create an ordering table using a [LISP association](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Association-Lists.html) to aid in your comparison function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a pretty standard type of Lisp exercise.  First you need a convenient way to figure out the ordering.  One easy way to is to keep a sequence of the pips (if you have lots, maybe a hash table mapping pips to positions would be better) and a function that compares their positions:

```
(defconstant +pips+ #(2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K A))

(defun pip< (pip1 pip2)
  (< (position pip1 +pips+)
     (position pip2 +pips+)))
```

Then you can use the standard [**sort**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_sort_.htm) function (remember, it's destructive, so save the result, and don't call it with quoted data, since you shouldn't modify literal data), passing **pip<** as the predicate and [**first**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_firstc.htm) as the key, because you use [**first**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_firstc.htm) to get the pip from each card (since you're representing cards as lists of a pip and a suit):

```
CL-USER> (let ((hand (copy-tree '((3 H)(2 H)(J D)(8 C)(5 C)))))
           (sort hand 'pip< :key 'first))
;=> ((2 H) (3 H) (5 C) (8 C) (J D))
```

Comment: Yeah, the `position` is simpler than the association suggestion I had made in my comment. (+1)

Comment: @lurker of course, it only scales so far. After that, it makes more sense to hash positions,or to write a comparison function directly.

Comment: I am trying to put a defparameter within the function so that I can work with it.

(defun poker (hand)
  (defparameter sortedhand (sort hand 'pip< :key 'first)))

Is there a problem with this? As it does not work.

Comment: @JT93 (i) That really sounds like a different question.  Stack Overflow is for single, specific programming questions.  This question was about sorting with a custom predicate.  A question about using defparameter within a function should really be a separate question (otherwise, people with the same problem are unlikely to look here to find the answer). (ii) "it does not work" is hardly descriptive enough to diagnose the problem.  Does it cause an error?  Does it run, but gives unexpected results? What did you attempt in trying to debug it?  Stack Overflow questions are expected to show ample

Comment: @JT93 debugging and research effort.  That's another reason that new questions are usually best posed as *new questions* rather than as comments on unrelated posts.

Comment: The problem is that our course gave us VERY limited understanding of LISP. Going for the practice of "here's some code look at it" rather than explaining it and this resulted in me finding it hard to diagnose any problem logically myself.  I realize now that my question was poorly worded and i apologize.

Comment: @JT93: Does the above answer the initial question well?If so this deserves an accept. As stated by Joshua you can ask more questions. Please give karma where it is due, stackoverflow is a community and this is how we work together